# How to get rid of empty spaces in report viewer C#?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I am using reportviewer in C# to print some data but I am facing a problem now which I am getting empty spaces in the right side of my report as the image shows [see report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlYiL.png)

I have done too much search on google and followed all steps  but still have the same problem,

1. My page is A4 with size: width: 21cm, height:29.7cm.
2. Body size: width : 17cm, height: 26cm.
3. Margin top: 1cm, button: 1cm, right: 1cm, left: 1cm

And I have set the `*ConsumerContainerWhitespace = true`.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

There are rulers in a report viewer designer. The top ruler shows the with of the layout of your report.

Change the width of your report layout to 17 sm. You shouldn't see any empty space on the left side your report designer.